# Estimating the x-intercept of an arbitrary monotonically increasing function

Tags: confidence-interval, function

I have a continuous monotonically increasing function, $f(x)$, whose $x$-intercept, $x^*$, I am trying to estimate. I have a dataset of $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs, with each $y_i=f(x_i)+\varepsilon_i$, where $\varepsilon_{i} \sim \text{Normal}(0, \sigma)$. The value of $\sigma$ is relatively large. The dataset includes a healthy mix of points above and below and the x-axis.

To estimate $x^*$, I sorted the datapoints so that $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$, and defined
$S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k y_i$. My estimate is then something like $x^* = x_{k^*}$, where $$k^* = \arg \min_k\ S_k$$

This estimate has served me well in my application thus far, but I've now begun wondering if I can meaningfully attach a confidence interval to my estimate. I understand this is a bit open-ended, but I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on this. Even a discussion of what sorts of assumptions might need to be made to make this question meaningful would be enlightening.

EDIT: An analysis of the expected bias of the above $x^*$ estimate would also be cool to see.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to find solution to $f(x)=0$? If so shouldn't there be a modulus of $S_k$ in your argmin expression?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the solution to $f(x)=0$. I believe the modulus I used is correct.

Comment: Do you know $\sigma$ or is it a nuisance parameter?

Comment: $\sigma$ is not known. I guess I should add that I perform this estimation on hundreds of datasets each week, each with its own $f, \sigma$, and each varying in sample size. So it needs to be a fully automated process; i.e., I don't have time to analyze whether I should try a linear fit, a logarithmic fit, etc.

Comment: re the edit. Consider the estimator $\hat{k}$ = $(\arg\min_k\ S_k + \arg\max_k\ \sum_{i=k+1}^n y_i)/2.$ Clearly it is unbiased: it is invariant under simultaneous negation of the $x_i$ and $y_i$, whence so is its expectation, and the only number invariant under negation is $0$.  This gives some potentially useful bounds on the bias. Saying any more about it would require being more specific about the class of $f$ under consideration.

Comment: Neat! Now...any ideas about confidence?